# how I can change some values of my json file?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, nested

I have a json file that is a list of dic. For an example the two elements of it are:

```
[{'key': 'chief information security officer',
  'top_transitions': [{'security architect': 5.0},
   {'cyber security manager': 3.0},
   {'information security officer': 3.0}]},
 {'key': 'security auditor',
  'top_transitions': [{'information security analyst': 9.0},
   {'information security officer': 9.0},
   {'it auditor': 6.0}]}]
```

I need to change some of the values of `top_transitions`  by my hand.For an example how I can change  `{'security architect': 5.0}` by `{'student': 15.0}`?

Comment: @MerajAhmed could you please write a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example to change `{"security architect": 5.0}` to `{"student": 15.0}` (`data` is loaded from your Json file):

```
import json

to_search = {"security architect": 5.0}
to_replace = {"student": 15.0}

for item in data:
    if to_search in item["top_transitions"]:
        item["top_transitions"].remove(to_search)
        item["top_transitions"].append(to_replace)


print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "chief information security officer",
        "top_transitions": [
            {
                "cyber security manager": 3.0
            },
            {
                "information security officer": 3.0
            },
            {
                "student": 15.0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "security auditor",
        "top_transitions": [
            {
                "information security analyst": 9.0
            },
            {
                "information security officer": 9.0
            },
            {
                "it auditor": 6.0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```